# Which format does static library (*.lib) files use? Where can I find "Official" specifications of *.LIB file structure/format?

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, mingw, static-libraries

Just now I found that static libraries in *nix systems, in other words *.a libraries
are nothing but archives of relocatables(*.o files) in  [ar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)#File_format_details) fromat.

1. What about static libraries(*.lib files) in windows? Which format are they in?
2. I found an article ([archived copy 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306062816/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/hood0498.aspx), [archived copy 2](http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_lib_file_format.htm)) which explains *.lib file structure. But Where can I find "Official" specifications of *.lib file structure/format?
3. Other than ar.exe of mingw is there any tool from Microsoft which extracts relocatable objects of *.lib & *.a files?

**EDIT:**

I wonder why I'm unable to get to this question. If there are no official specifications. Then how does the compiler ('linker' to be more correct) writers work with *.LIB files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that *.LIB file uses the [`ar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)#File_format_details) file format.

**Official Specifications:** Section 7. "Archive (Library) File Format" of [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20100314154747/http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx) describes this format.

Comment: The linked specification is a docx file, here is a webpage with the current specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format#archive-library-file-format

Answer (score 2):

mingw's `ar` works just fine on *.lib files - even ones created under VisualStudio.

We've actually used it in the past to pull out parts of a library we needed when it contained some other stuff we couldn't link with (due to conflicts with other libraries). Kinda hacky, but it works.

Comment: Thats a useful piece of info. But does this mean that *.lib files are also in `ar` format? May be, mingw's ar.exe is abstracting the underlying format and behaving in the same way.

Comment: Don't really know. I was mostly answering #3 I guess.