# Can't get libcurl working (linker error)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, libcurl

I'm trying for several days to get libcurl working with my project and I'm getting insane with it. I'm acting as it is written in instructions and I get errors all the time. This is what I do step by step:

[https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411514/7281660) on this website in download wizard I picked option *"Source code"* then *"Platform Independent"* (because I couldn't find windows here) and downloaded the file.

I launched *"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"* got into *C:\Users\PC\Downloads\curl-7.58.0\curl-7.58.0\winbuild* using *"cd"* command and then typed (I'm not sure about VC=17 option - in instruction they say that the value for it can be from <9,15>, but there wasn't any error when I type 17)  *"nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17 DEBUG=yes MACHINE=x64*" and get error as below:

> "..\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib/file.obj
>   : fata l error LNK1112: wystąpił konflikt typu maszyny modułu "x86" z
>   typem maszyny doc elowej "x64" NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
>   \Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe"": kod
>   powrotu "0x 458" Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
>   \Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"": kod
>   powrotu "0 x2" Stop. "

telling something about conflict of module machine type "x86" with target machine "x64" - wierd because my machine is 64bit (Windows 7 64bit).

I've tried once again with machine changed to x86: *"nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17 DEBUG=yes MACHINE=x86"* - **I get no error(wierd, because I think that previous error should occur now**

Then I went to *"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\curl-7.58.0\curl-7.58.0\builds\libcurl-vc17-x86-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl"*, where I found 3 folders: bin, include, lib.

I created new visual studio 2017 empty project. Created source file and pasted an example code I had found on internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

in *Solution Explorer->MyProject->Properties(configuration-debug, platform- win32)->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories* - I added here path: *C:\Users\PC\Downloads\curl-7.58.0\curl-7.58.0\builds\libcurl-vc17-x86-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include*

then in *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories* - I added: *C:\Users\PC\Downloads\curl-7.58.0\curl-7.58.0\builds\libcurl-vc17-x86-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib*

and then in *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* I added the name of generated *.lib file from the folder above - *libcurl_a_debug.lib*

Finally, I clicked on *Build -> Build solution* and in the "Output" window I get:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: libcurltest, Configuration: Debug x64
>   ------ 1>Source.cpp 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_strerror referenced in function main
>   1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_curl_easy_init referenced in function main 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_setopt referenced
>   in function main 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp_curl_easy_perform referenced in function main
>   1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function main 1>C:\Users\PC\source\repos\libcurltest\Dependencies\lib\libcurl_a_debug.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   1>C:\Users\PC\source\repos\libcurltest\x64\Debug\libcurltest.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals 1>Done building project
>   "libcurltest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

It looks like the linker couldn't see my library despite that I've added it. What could be a problem?

EDIT:
[If I added #define CURL_STATICLIB on the begining of Source.cpp it now compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411514/7281660) , but I still don't understand why I couldn't compile libcurl for x64 platform

Comment: linker say you that can not find `__imp_curl_easy_strerror` in any lib or obj find. set yourself on linker place - you can find `__imp_curl_easy_strerror` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include libcurl to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398209/include-libcurl-to-microsoft-visual-studio-2015)